# Appending tabindex to input tag using JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to set the tabindex for input fields but I don't have access to the HTML.

We are inserting a form that is generated from a third party. This form has two fields, postal code and email address, in that order. I want to rearrange them (without having to modify the field on the source platform) using CSS so email is above postal code, but obviously this messes up the tab order.

The inputs have name attributes of PostalCode and EmailAddress respectively. I know very little about JS so am trying to kludge this together from resources on the Internet and so far with no success.

I have tried the following but it doesn't work and I am obviously unable to figure out why or how to do it properly.

```
document.getElementsByName("EmailAddress")[0].setAttribute("tabIndex", "1");
document.getElementsByName("PostalCode")[0].setAttribute("tabIndex", "2");
document.getElementsByClass("at-submit")[0].setAttribute("tabIndex", "3");
```

Comment: Aaron, are you running your code once the DOM is loaded?

Comment: @Bibberty I think so, given what little I know — the full script is

    $(document).ready(function() {
    
    document.getElementsByName("EmailAddress")[0].setAttribute("tabIndex", "1");
    document.getElementsByName("PostalCode")[0].setAttribute("tabIndex", "2");
    document.getElementsByClass("at-submit")[0].setAttribute("tabIndex", "3");

    });

Answer (score 0):

This works.

Notice I just increment the element to have a higher index.

```js
const displayTabIndex = (name, { tabIndex }) => console.log(`${name} - ${tabIndex}`);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const tel = document.querySelector('input[type="tel"');
  const pCode = document.querySelector('input[name="PostalCode"]');
  displayTabIndex('tel', tel);
  displayTabIndex('pCode', pCode);

  pCode.setAttribute('tabIndex', 3);
  
  displayTabIndex('tel', tel);
  displayTabIndex('pCode', pCode); 
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="tel" name="tel" tabindex="2">
  <input type="text" name="PostalCode" tabindex="1">
</form>
```

Comment: This did not work for my case unfortunately. I'm not sure if I am implementing it wrong or if I didn't adequately explain my use case here. The inputs I am targeting have no id. Here is the PostalCode input for example:

<input type="tel" autocomplete="postal-code" x-autocompletetype="postal-code" pattern="^\d{5}([\-]\d{4})?$" required="" accesskey="p" title="Postal Code (required)" name="PostalCode" value="" maxlength="10" placeholder="Postal Code*">

Comment: I changed the querySelector and PostalCode element to match what you have, does it work now?

Comment: Unfortunately this produced no noticeable change.  

Comment length precludes me from pasting all the inputs involved, but there's the one above which is currently the 1st input but I want it 2nd.  

The 2nd field (which I want 1st) has attr. type=email and name=EmailAddress  

And last is submit button which is an input (not a button) with type=submit and class .at-submit  

Tab order is currently postal, email, submit and I am trying to get it to email, postal, submit  

I appreciate your help, I feel like a big dunce here

Comment: Have to go out now. Will look in the morning if you have not solved. Can you perhaps put code into a jsfiddle and we work on it there?

Comment: Certainly — https://jsfiddle.net/0yo73b9e/

Here is the full form HTML generated by the third party script. There is a lot of superfluous stuff here, all we need to concern ourselves with is switching around this tab order. Whole problem here is that I cannot reliably get access to the platform the form is built on from the client, so I am trying to work around it, but I am a designer and not much of a developer.

Comment: Ok - https://jsfiddle.net/8u3ehLgv/ here is working version. The issue was that the elements had a tabindex of 0. Which is `auto` so they both need to be set for the order to correctly change.

Comment: Thank you — I see this works in the jsfiddle, but when I run it on the site I see the following errors in the chrome console:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'displayTabIndex' has already been declared
    at (index):218
jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
(index):13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'tabIndex' of 'object null' as it is null.
    at displayTabIndex ((index):13)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):19)

Comment: Get rid of displayTabIndex and my calls to it. They are only for test. Looks like the method name clashes with a library you have loaded. Then you should be good to go.

Comment: That has cleared up the uncaught syntaxerror but not the uncaught TypeErrors. This is my edited code you provided: https://jsfiddle.net/sm3nkryo/